# The data(username,passwords) stored in app bundle is safe in a jailbroken ios device

Tags: encryption, penetration-test, file-encryption, data-leakage, jailbreak

I was testing an iphone application in a jail broken device. I happend to see an intresting thing that the username and passwords are stored in a plist file and Cache.db file in preferences directory of app bundle.  I can see this data as cleartext. So the data stored in nsuserdefault, plist, sqlite are not safe right? I have checked the other storage options like Keychains. But there is a tool keychain dumper,which can easily dump the keychain data.. So how i can save data in iphone app.  Nothing is safe. So any alternate method to save data, I mean any kind of encryption or anything. How you advice me to secury store a data even if the phone is jailbreaked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app checks if the device is jailbroken and refuses to run if it is. That's it.

On a jailbroken device, a hacker (or the user) can modify installed applications, so nothing is safe.

Comment: Is there any kind of encryption help us to protect the data?